# Do you understand what this code is aiming to do?

Tags: java, parsing

I never write here, but as almost everyone I often read questions and answers... now it's my time to ask :)

So, I was reading a long piece of code that works on a stream of bytes to decode tags and values of ePassports (ICAO Doc 9303 defines the International Technical Specifications)... it wasn't difficult until I found this part (I placed comments before and after the cryptic part)

```
int len = s.read(); // s is an InputStream    
readPos++;
if ((len > 0x80)) {
    int lenlen = len - 0x80;
    len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i < lenlen); i++) {
        if ((readPos == length)) {
            throw new ParseException();
        }
        // wtf begin
        len = (len << 8) | ((byte) (s.read()));
        // wtf end
        readPos++;
    }
}
size = readPos + len;
```

I understand that it reads from an InputStream, byte by byte, and increases the position in the byte stream, but why does it perform the shift and save the result in the variable len? If I'm not wrong, len gets overwritten over and over, so how could this variable have a meaningful value after the for loop?

Comment: It's reading len variable byte by byte. Most significant byte goes first. Than you multiply by 8 (size of byte) and  add next byte (here written with bitwise or). Think of reading a number digit by digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is processing `lenlen` number of bytes, and making out of those bytes a big endian number:

- case len was <= 128

  `if` is not entered, and `len` represents a single byte number
- case len == 128+1, +2, +3, +4

  Respectively 1, 2, 3, 4 bytes are used: every byte is placed at the least
  significant position and where the older bytes are shifted a byte position to the left (`<< 8`). So 129 for a 1 byte length (for numbers between 128 and 255),
  and 130 for a 2 bytes number.
- at the end: `len` bytes are skipped.

Data integrity would require to check for the original len >= 0, and len <= 128 + 4 and for the calculated `len` being >= 0 too.

---

***The writing process*** The inverse algorithm you might encounter:

```
if (len <= 128) {
    out.write((byte)len);
} else {
    int bytes = 4 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeroes(len) / 8;
    out.write(128 + bytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; ++i) {
        int b = len >>>(bytes - 1);
        out.write((byte)b); // Truncates the int to just 1 byte.
    }
}
```

(Assuming `len` is positive.)

Comment: Joop, mate, you're awesome. Your example also helps a lot understanding the core concept.